# ¿Cómo hago para que un div ocupe el 100% de el ancho de la pantalla con css?

Tags: html, css

Necesito que un div ocupe el 100% de el ancho en ambos lados pero no se como se hace

Comment: con width: 100%

Comment: igual no se ancha de el todo

Comment: @Ringoelie por favor lee [ask] y provee un [mcve] de otro modo tu pregunta quedará cerrada

Comment: me confundí, es poner margin: 0 y padding: 0

Comment: Hola @Ringoelie, todo elemento de bloque ocupa el espacio horizontal disponible. Por lo tanto, no es necesario aplicar `width: 100%` ni `width: 100vw`.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas mostrar algo de codigo o referencia de lo que tratas de decir, tu pregunta es muy generativo

Pero algo de idea de lo que tratas de decir

```
.hijo{
  width:100vw;
}
```

Comment: Pregunta  ¿por qué darle un ancho definido así a un elemento que al ser en bloque de hecho va a ocupar todo el ancho disponible de su contenedor?

Comment: listo ya lo solucione muchas gracias